# Finding tangents of interior angles given slopes of triangle sides

Tags: trigonometry, triangles, analytic-geometry, angle, slope

(I know there are previous posts here on finding the parameters of a triangle, but those questions are based on pure geometry, while mine is based on coordinate geometry and slopes, so I guess asking a separate question is okay.)

---

Apparently, if $m_1$, $m_2$, and $m_3$ are the slopes of three lines $L_1=0$, $L_2=0$, and $L_3=0$, where $m_1\gt m_2\gt m_3$, then the interior angles of the triangle, say $\Delta ABC$, formed by the lines are given by;
$$\tan{A} =\frac{m_1-m_2}{1+m_1m_2}\\\tan{B} =\frac{m_2-m_3}{1+m_2m_3} \\\tan{C} =\frac{m_3-m_1}{1+m_1m_3} $$
How is it possible to find the correct *interior* angles this way in every case? As I understand it, each of the tan values could represent either the acute or the obtuse angles between the lines, but this theorem has the slopes in the numerators subtracted in just the right way so as to somehow produce the correct sign for the tangents of the angles formed.

All I could figure out was that if you subtracted the smaller slope from the larger in this type of difference-of-angles tan equation, you would get:

1. A positive value for two lines whose slopes are both negative or both positive, and
2. If the lines have opposite signs for their slopes, a positive value if the acute angle between the lines is horizontal, and a negative value if the acute angle opens up vertically.

If correct, I suspect that can be used to prove the result, but I'm not sure how. Could someone help me prove the theorem? (The proof doesn't necessarily have to incorporate my attempt if it's cumbersome or if there's a better way; apart from helping with the proof, verifying if my attempt was correct would be enough.)

Comment: @DougM: that doesn't seem intuitive, though. And I [graphed](https://imgur.com/a/xVNOY9E) it out, and all the triangles seem to have the same angles.

Comment: Sorry, you are right.  If $L_1,L_2,L_3$ are listed in counter-clockwise order, you get angles A,B,C.  If they are in clockwise order, you get their suplements.

Comment: What do you mean by proclaiming that three *lines* are equal to $0$??

Comment: Consider this question: suppose you have two rays with slopes $m_1, m_2$ eminating from the origin, with the second ray counter-clockwise from the first (and not at a right angle). Now create a second coordinate system with the same origin, but the positive $x$-axis is the first ray. What is the slope of the second ray in this new coordinate system? If you can figure out the answer to that, it will give the proof you are after.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: I meant the line equations, as in $ax+by+c=0$. Sorry if it wasn't clear, haha.

Comment: @PaulSinclair: Using the tan-formula by subtracting the smaller slope from the larger would yield the slope of the second ray you mentioned; generally, the tan formula used that way would give the tan value of the angle formed by going anticlockwise from the line with lower slope to the one with higher slope. I'm still not sure how this works with the three triangle angles, though.

Comment: Actually write out the formula for the new slope in terms of the slopes of the two rays in the original coordinate system. If you do that, the relevance should be obvious.